# Main action in scrollview

Tags: accessibility, scrolling

Our app has a similar welcome screen layout to this:

http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/comment-page-1/

The action buttons are at the bottom of a scrollview, so when the text is long, you can't see them. At first I thought this is bad, but then I ran to the above article. It says you might want the user to read through the text before moving on. Is this a good practice or should you avoid it?

I think it's not an accessibility issue for blind users because the button texts are recognized and announced by text readers. But it might be for others.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend in the first view if the container show limited caracters of the text (maybe 350 characters, depends on spacings and font size) and add "(more)" at the end of that limited view, which will be followed by buttons under this text. Then you can always make sure that your users will see those buttons, in the meantime they are able to click more and read the entire content details. The more action expands the container to show the rest of the content; however, user still knows about buttons underneath of that container, so even if they haven't clicked on those yet they will scrol down to click.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how important the text is that the user is reading.

If it's just information the user might need... maybe entered information would be a better description, then the accept button should ALWAYS be displayed.

However, if there's some critical warning or license agreement the user must acknowledge then the user should be forced to scroll through the entire text BEFORE the accept button becomes available. Be frugal with this approach. Don't make the user do this each time they open a tool or visit a page. Instead, save their response.